# Can you Use word_diff with Gitlab?

Tags: ms-word, diff, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I am looking to use microsoft word documents with Gitlab and would like to have it track the changes. I found [word_diff here.](https://github.com/benbalter/word_diff) It has instructions for github but not for gitlab, and I'm uncertain where to set variables in Gitlab or even if it works the same way. I'd be happy to use some other solution with gitlab if it exists for word documents. Thanks for the help ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't use word_diff with GitLab because the WebHook specifications for GitLab and GitHub differ. You would need to adjust things such as key and header names.

- Different Web Hook specifications for [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/help/web_hooks/web_hooks.md) and [GitHub](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)
- [Difference in key names](https://github.com/benbalter/word_diff/blob/master/lib/word_diff.rb#L50)